# Youtube API - Use "this" to play the current video

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube-api

I'm using the youtube API and I want to play the current video that is clicked and stop it too but my problem is that I'm using the same ID for each video and I want to use the selector "this" to play or stop the current video but I don't know how to do it.

This is my code:

```html
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="embeded-video">
  <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="348" height="196"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&rel=0"
    frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="controls">
  <input type="button" value="Play" onclick="play();">
  <div id="stop">Stop</div>
</div>

<div class="embeded-video">
  <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="348" height="196"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&rel=0"
    frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="controls">
  <input type="button" value="Play" onclick="play();">
  <div id="stop">Stop</div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#stop").click(function(){
    var video = $(this).closest(".controls").prev().find("#player").attr("src");
    $(this).closest(".controls").prev().find("#player").attr("src","");
    $(this).closest(".controls").prev().find("#player").attr("src",video);
 });
  });

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player');
  }
  function play(){
    player.playVideo();
    player.setVolume(100);
  }
</script>
```

Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ramanbedi1989/xbxzzvzx/1/) can help you. Basically I have made a generic code that requires a video container div to be added to your code just to identify the container of each video and play or stop the specific video.

```
var players = {};
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  $('.player').each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var playerId = $this.attr('id');
      players[playerId] = new YT.Player(playerId);
  });
}
$('.play').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var currentPlayer = $this.parents('.video-container').find('.player');
  players[currentPlayer.attr('id')].playVideo();
});
$('.stop').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var currentPlayer = $this.parents('.video-container').find('.player');
  players[currentPlayer.attr('id')].stopVideo();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to check it